# Insert Cursor Having an Issue With Reading the Syntax of a List

Tags: arcpy, python, cursor, list, syntax

In my code below, how do I get the **Desired Output?**

```
# Get a list of all 'SITE_NFID' in the dashboard_site_summary table that don't have a match in the nfid_fqn_associations table
dashboard_site_summary_list = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dashboard_site_summary, ['SITE_NFID']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] not in nfa_dict:
            dashboard_site_summary_list.append(row[0]))

# Insert the NFID's into the SHP_Report that didn't have a NFA match to ensure ALL dashboard_site_summary NFID's are accounted
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(shp_report, ['SITE_NFID'])
for item in dashboard_site_summary_list:
    cursor.insertRow(item)
```

Current output in the "*dashboard_site_summary_list*":

Current Output = `['1903BRUF.65', '1903BRUF.65']`<---Doesn't work
Desired Output = `[(('1903BRUF.65'),),(('1903BRUF.65'),)]` <----------Works

Article I found showing correct syntax: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011654

My best attempt to fix the output of the list:

```
# Get a list of all 'SITE_NFID' in the dashboard_site_summary table that don't have a match in the nfid_fqn_associations table
dashboard_site_summary_list = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dashboard_site_summary, ['SITE_NFID']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] not in nfa_dict:
            dashboard_site_summary_list.append('((' + str(row[0]) + ',),')
```

Comment: I cant test now but focus on `cursor.insertRow(item)` and keep your "current output". Try `cursor.insertRow([item])` or `cursor.insertRow((item,))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The input to `insertRow()` [must be a list or tuple](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm).

Instead of building this as a string value as listed above,

```
dashboard_site_summary_list.append('((' + str(row[0]) + ',),')
```

append a tuple:

```
dashboard_site_summary_list.append((row[0],))  # don't forget the comma; see below for type comparison
```

or list (whichever you prefer):

```
dashboard_site_summary_list.append([row[0]]) # doesn't matter whether you include the comma here

>>> test = ('15')
>>> type(test)
<class 'str'>
>>> test = ('15',)
>>> type(test)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Or, you can leave the output as it currently is, and just add the syntax for tuple or list on the `insertRow()` step.

```
cursor.insertRow((item,)) #don't forget the comma
```

or

```
cursor.insertRow([item])
```